# react axios not providing a response

Tags: axios

My code is as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const getBannerStatus = () => {     
    let url = `http://localhost:3000` + apiConstants.API_POST_BANNERSTATUS;   
    axios.post(url)    
        .then(response => {
            console.log("axios response = " + response);
            return response.data.bannerStatus;
        });     
}
```

I have tested with chrome dev tools and it is stepping into the axios module.  I have tested the URL and getting `JSON` back aka `response.data` without an issue in POSTMAN.

JSON returned from POSTMAN call.

```
{
    "bannerMessage": null,
    "bannerHeader": null,
    "result": "success",
    "bannerStatus": "HIDE"
}
```

However the axios code is not returning a response, in fact it is not even providing the `console.log("axios response = " + response);`

Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was missing header information. The following code is working.

```
const getBannerStatus = () => {
  let url = `http://localhost:3000` + apiConstants.API_POST_BANNERSTATUS;
  axios.post(url,{},{
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate",
        pragma: "no-cache",
        Expires: 0,
      }
      })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("axios response = " + response.data.bannerStatus);
      return response.data.bannerStatus;
    });
};
```